# Как получить координаты всех точек в окружности в Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

```
shape_id = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 40, 40, outline="red", 
    fill="green", width=20)
```

Есть круг в холсте. Мне нужно получить координаты всех точек, которые находятся по площади круга, для того чтобы создать событие соприкосновения двух кругов.(если можно сделать это по-другому, то я не против)

Comment: это лишнее.у тебя есть 2 точки вот и сравни их с другими двумя. на деле незаметно будет расчитывать столкнулись 2 круга или расчитывать что столкнулись 2 квадрата. но это быстрее и легче.

Comment: Два круга соприкасаются или пересекаются, если расстояние между их центрами меньше или равно сумме радиусов этих кругов.